PNG to solidified render (geometry nodes?)
I used to use Blender years ago ~2.8, but since then I've become a programmer so I'm not really up-to-date. A friend asked me if I could help batch-processing pngs to become these solidified renders. I attached a crude example below which I made quickly manually.
I'm not sure if this would be possible with geometry nodes. I want to create a template for my friend so that they could just drop in a png image, hit F12 and save the render. It it's not possible from a png, possibly they would provide an svg / png pair, so that the model could be extruded/solidified from the path while the material would use the image texture.
My other idea was to write a plugin for it but I don't do python so the whole thing is probably out of scope.
Any ideas, recommendations, pointers are welcome.
Thanks, cheers!

The image above is a render that I did in Blender. I imported an SVG (cutout of the cat), UV-unwrapped it, applied a texture (image texture of the cat), and a material, then put on a Solidify modifier and rendered it.
This is the process I'd like to "automate" so that it doesn't have to be done manually every time, instead, the user just drops in the image and can render the scene.

It definitely is possible to import SVG's as curves... not sure how exactly you could then fill in the faces and extrude while keeping the texture in the right spot though... definitely should be possible I reckon.

If you want to get a full 3D scene from a single image, it isn't possible natively in Blender. It's slowly becoming possible with AIs. What PNGs are you talking about ? What do you mean "solidified renders" ? What is this image you showed us ? Could you show us your input PNG/SVG and an example of what you want to get exactly ?

@Lutzi The image above is a render that I did in Blender - I imported an svg (cutout of the cat), uv-unwrapped it, applied a texture (image texture of the cat), and a material, then put on a solidify modifier and rendered it. This is the process I'd like to "automate" so that it doesn't have to be done manually every time, instead the user just drops in the Image and can render the scene.

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

I managed to solve it with geometry nodes as suspected. The way this works is that the grid node produces a vertex grid of desired resulotion, then the delete geometry node deletes unneeded vertices based on the alpha map from the png. The rest is straightforward stuff, transforms, face triangulation, extruding, UV generation and so on. Input png has to be of 1:1 ratio. Here's the node setup for geometry:

and here's to one for the shader:

